How Do I Gather All Intersecting Lists?
So, I have a list of pairs:
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, {10, 
11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13, 7}, {6, 14}, {14, 4}, {3, 15}, {15, 
1}};

Graph@list view:

I need to gather all pairs that have a common element. I thought this is the way to do it:
gathered = Gather[list, IntersectingQ]

Which outputs:

{{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {15, 1}}, {{4, 5}, {5, 6}, {14, 4}}, {{7, 8}, {8,
9}, {13, 7}}, {{9, 10}, {10, 11}}, {{11, 12}, {12, 13}}, {{6,
14}}, {{3, 15}}}

That's 7 lists, please note {3,15} was supposed to end up in the first one. What is the proper way to do it, so I get what I expect, which is:

{{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {15, 1}, {3, 15}}, {{4, 5}, {5, 6}, {14, 4}, {6,
14}}, {{9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {13,
7}}}

,which is 3 lists with all intersecting pairs?
NB!
Edited: solutions summarized in my 
answer below.

I suspect that the issue with using Gather is that it expects some sort of equivalence relation, but IntersectingQ isn't transitive. Something like that. It seems like what Gather is doing is finding all the lists that are connected to {1,2}, then removing these from the remaining list, then starting with the first one that doesn't connect, which is {4,5}, and continuing that process. It's not iterative.

@Anton You might want to check your solution https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/307755/58868 for list = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13, 7}, {6, 14}, {14, 4}, {3, 15}, {15, 1}, {1, 99}}; ...

@vindobona thank you! I see what happende.. will update my solution.

@Anton regarding your update using WeaklyConnectedComponents, your approach of recovering the original pairs with ReplaceAll is still giving incorrect results for the more general test cases I provided. If there are constraints on your problem that make this not an issue, then you should clarify what those are.

@lericr okay guess DeleteDuplicates must be invoked :)

But that's not the only problem. Try it on this list: list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}} .

@lericr I don't see a problem with list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}. What is the problem with it?

You will lose a pair. See my updated answer.

Now that I think about it, this is exactly why your solution is faster. The algorithm for ConnectedComponents is free to discard information about edges.

I suggest you [edit] this post and leave only the initial question, and move other things to your answer. Otherwise, this post is getting really long and confusing. The purpose of a question is that it contains the question, while answers should be posted separately :)

@Domen done [v]

Solution V1.0: Naive Approach
list={{1,2},{2,3},{4,5},{5,6},{7,8},{8,9},{9,10},{10,11},{11,12},{12,13},{13,7},{6,14},{14,4},{3,15},{15,1}};

antonV10naive=ConnectedComponents@list/.Join[AssociationThread[list[[All, 1]]->list],AssociationThread[list[[All, 2]]->list]]


{{{13, 7}, {7, 8}, {12, 13}, {8, 9}, {11, 12}, {9, 10}, {10,
11}}, {{14, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 14}, {5, 6}}, {{15, 1}, {1, 2}, {3,
15}, {2, 3}}}

As pointed out by @vindobona, this solution breaks down with list like this:
listVindobona = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 
10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13, 7}, {6, 14}, {14, 4}, {3, 
15}, {15, 1}, {1, 99}};

@lericr discovered that it also breaks in two special cases:
listlericr1 = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}};(* creates duplicate {4,5} *)

listlericr2 = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};(* looses the {1,3} pair *)

Solution V1.2: Issues Fixed
To address these three issues, the improved v1.2 approach was developed:
antonV12fixed=Map[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[#,1]&,WeaklyConnectedComponents[Rule@@@list]/.Merge[{PositionIndex[list[[All,1]]],PositionIndex[list[[All,2]]]},Flatten]/.AssociationThread[Range@Length@list->list]]

Solution V2.0 - Alternative Solution
This one relies on Nearest. It's pretty fast but not as fast as v1.2. or @vindobona 's solution.
Map[list[[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[#]]]]&,Ceiling[Map[Nearest[Flatten@list->"Index",#]&,WeaklyConnectedComponents[Rule@@@list]]*.5]]

Solution V3.0: using GroupBy
This is so far the fastest way I've found:
Map[Union@Flatten[#,1]&,WeaklyConnectedComponents[Rule@@@list]/.Merge[{GroupBy[list,First],GroupBy[list,Last]},Flatten[#,1]&]]

Testing & Timings
listVindobona={{1,2},{2,3},{4,5},{5,6},{7,8},{8,9},{9,10},{10,11},{11,12},{12,13},{13,7},{6,14},{14,4},{3,15},{15,1},{1,99}};
listlericr1={{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{4,5},{5,6}};
listlericr2={{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{3,4}};

list=listVindobona;

{t1,ubpdqn}=VertexList/@ConnectedGraphComponents[RelationGraph[IntersectingQ[#1,#2]&&#1!=#2&,list]]//RepeatedTiming;

{t2,Syed}=DeleteCases[(ConnectedGraphComponents[list]//Map[EdgeList])/.UndirectedEdge->List//Map[SortBy[First]],{}]//RepeatedTiming;

{t3,march}=FixedPoint[Flatten[#,1]&/@Gather[#,Or@@Flatten@Outer[IntersectingQ,#1,#2,1]&]&,List/@list]//RepeatedTiming;

{t4,antonV12}=Map[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[#,1]&,WeaklyConnectedComponents[Rule@@@list]/.Merge[{PositionIndex[list[[All,1]]],PositionIndex[list[[All,2]]]},Flatten]/.AssociationThread[Range@Length@list->list]]//RepeatedTiming;

{t5,lericr}=DeleteCases[Apply[List,EdgeList/@ConnectedGraphComponents@list,{2}],{}]//RepeatedTiming;

{t6,antonV20}=Map[list[[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[#]]]]&,Ceiling[Map[Nearest[Flatten@list->"Index",#]&,WeaklyConnectedComponents[Rule@@@list]]*.5]]//RepeatedTiming;

connectedPairs[list_]:=With[{ds=CreateDataStructure["DisjointSet"]},ds["InsertAll",Flatten@list];Map[ds["Unify",Sequence@@#]&,list];Map[s|->Select[ds["CommonSubsetQ",#[[1]],s]&]@list,ds["Subsets"][[All,1]]]];
{t7,vindobona}=connectedPairs[list]//RepeatedTiming;

{t8,antonV30}=Map[Union@Flatten[#,1]&,WeaklyConnectedComponents[Rule@@@list]/.Merge[{GroupBy[list,First],GroupBy[list,Last]},Flatten[#,1]&]]//RepeatedTiming;
Sort[Sort/@antonV12]==Sort[Sort/@antonV20]==Sort[Sort/@ubpdqn]==Sort[Sort/@Syed]==Sort[Sort/@march]==Sort[Sort/@lericr]==Sort[Sort/@vindobona]==Sort[Sort/@antonV30]


True


Performance At Scale:
I've tested all algos with
list=Complement[Union[Sort/@RandomInteger[{1,n},{n,2}]],Transpose[{r=Range@n,r}]];

,with n being equal to 20, 50, 100, 500 and 1000.

UPD Dec 18, 2024.
I stumbled upon yet slightly more efficient approach:
{t9, antonV40} = 
  Union /@ 
     Flatten /@ (WeaklyConnectedComponents@(UndirectedEdge @@@ 
           list) /. 
        Merge[{AssociationThread[list[[All, 1]], 
           r = Range@Length@list], 
          AssociationThread[list[[All, 2]], r]}, Identity]) /. 
    AssociationThread[r, list] // RepeatedTiming;

Updated timings:


This is a nice approach, but as you've done it here, it's not quite correct. I'll write up an answer to explain.

You're right. I've written V2 to address the issues you've found.

Very nice. Great to see iterative improvements and comparisons

I think I fixed V1 approach with Merge@PositionIndex

GroupBy was the secret sause. Fastest so far.

Turns out, ReplaceAll beats them all :)

You can use RelationGraph, e.g.
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, {10, 
    11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13, 7}, {6, 14}, {14, 4}, {3, 15}, {15, 
    1}};
r = RelationGraph[IntersectingQ[#1, #2] && #1 != #2 &, list]
VertexList /@ ConnectedGraphComponents[r]


{{{7, 8}, {8, 9}, {13, 7}, {9, 10}, {12, 13}, {10, 11}, {11, 
   12}}, {{4, 5}, {5, 6}, {14, 4}, {6, 14}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {15, 
   1}, {3, 15}}}

Would need modification depending on specific needs, esp for different lists.
Or a slight variant using DistanceMatrix and custom DistanceFunction and then same graph functions:
m = DistanceMatrix[list, 
    DistanceFunction -> (Length[Intersection[#1, #2]] &)] /. 2 -> 0;
list[[VertexList[#]]] & /@ ConnectedGraphComponents[AdjacencyGraph[m]]


Ok, I see. So, there's basically, no way to achieve the goal via list manipulations ?

@Anton you can  do with list manipulation. I just found the graph in-built functions useful for these sort of tasks.  They are just optimized ways of doing pairwise comparisons and then  gathering after that. I just started the answering. Other users will have other ways. I have found the variety of approaches to achieve goal both a strength of Mathematica/Wolfram Language and this site.  Play and you will probably achieve result using other functions. Good luck :)

Wow :) Ok, thank you!

For what it's worth, I don't think the second condition in your RelationGraph is necessary. I.e. you could just do r = RelationGraph[IntersectingQ[#1, #2] &, list]. The self-relation will come out in the wash.

Even shorter: r = RelationGraph[IntersectingQ, list] .

Yes you are right as the only requirement is to get vertices and this does not depend on edges

This is pretty clunky/klugey, I think, but here's a way to do it using iterative Gather list manipulations.  (I include this mainly to point out why Gather doesn't work on its own: it's because Gather seems to assume that the function used to detect equality is an equivalence relation, and the one outlined in the OP is not.)
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, {10, 11},
    {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13, 7}, {6, 14}, {14, 4}, {3, 15}, {15, 1}};
FixedPoint[
   Flatten[#, 1] & /@ Gather[#, Or @@ Flatten@Outer[IntersectingQ, #1, #2, 1] &] &,
   List /@ list
  ]
(* {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {15, 1}, {3, 15}},
    {{4, 5}, {5, 6}, {14, 4}, {6, 14}},
    {{7, 8}, {8, 9}, {13, 7}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}}} *)

The issue with using one Gather command is that it seems to assume that the test function that goes in the second slot is transitive. However, IntersectingQ is a non-transitive relation, since {1,2} intersects {2,3} which in turn intersects {3,4}, but {1,2} and {3,4} don't intersect. Gather doesn't seem to "back-check" its gathered lists; that is, it goes through the list sequentially, and once it's Gathered an element, it doesn't then use that element to check against the other elements in the list.
This version iteratively Gathers elements by checking to see if any list in the already-Gathered list intersects any element of another of the already-Gathered lists, combining them if so.  The Outer command is the one that checks all two-element lists against each other, the Flatten command turns the Gathered list back into a list of ordered pairs.  Finally, FixedPoint makes the process recursive, and stops once the output doesn't change anymore.
It is beyond likely that using the built-in graph functionality will be much faster.

list = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, {10, 
    11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13, 7}, {6, 14}, {14, 4}, {3, 15}, {15, 
    1}};

DeleteCases[(ConnectedGraphComponents[list] // Map[EdgeList]) /. 
  UndirectedEdge -> List // Map[SortBy[First]],{}]



{{{7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13,     7}},
{{4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 14}, {14, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3,     15}, {15,
1}}}


Generates extra {}s from list={{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, {10,    11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13, 7}, {6, 14}, {14, 4}, {3, 15}, {15,    1}, {1, 99}}. Fixed with DeleteCases.

Just another version using DisjointSet DataStructure :
connectedPairs[list_] :=
  With[{ds = CreateDataStructure["DisjointSet"]},
    ds["InsertAll", Flatten@list];
    Map[ds["Unify", Sequence @@ #] &, list];
    Map[s |-> Select[ds["CommonSubsetQ", #[[1]], s] &]@list, ds["Subsets"][[All, 1]]]]

list=
  {{1,2},{2,3},{4,5},{5,6},{7,8}
  ,{8,9},{9,10},{10,11},{11,12},{12,13}
  ,{13,7},{6,14},{14,4},{3,15},{15,1},{1,99}};

connectedPairs[list] 

(*
  {{{1,2},{2,3},{3,15},{15,1},{1,99}}
  ,{{4,5},{5,6},{6,14},{14,4}}
  ,{{7,8},{8,9},{9,10},{10,11},{11,12},{12,13},{13,7}}}}
*)


Wow, this one is fast, too! @vindobona , nice algo.

@Anton Thank you for your feedback! The DisjointSet structure seems well-suited to the current context. Regarding performance, I did some tests using different distributions e.g. RandomInteger[m, {n, 2}] and the timing varies a lot...

Guess it could run yet faster, if you replace Select with something as fast as Nearest etc., but it's a wild guess, I'm not really sure it could be done.

This is just a slight correction (at least as I understood the problem) to the answer provided by the OP, @Anton. It is a very nice strategy, but it doesn't generalize and it doesn't reconstruct the connected components correctly according to the original list. For reference, here is @Anton's general strategy for a given list of pairs:
ConnectedComponents@list /. 
  Join[
    AssociationThread[list[[All, 1]] -> list],
    AssociationThread[list[[All, 2]] -> list]]

Not generalizable
Let's say our list of pairs looks like this:
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {10, 11}}

When we interpret this as edges of a graph, we will end up with vertices 4,5,6,7,8,9 just because of the default way WL builds graphs.
ConnectedComponents@list
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {10, 11}, {9}, {8}, {7}, {6}, {5}, {4}} *)

ConnectedComponents@list /. Join[AssociationThread[list[[All, 1]] -> list], AssociationThread[list[[All, 2]] -> list]]
(* {{{1, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{10, 11}, {10, 11}}, {9}, {8}, {7}, {6}, {5}, {4}} *)

Creates duplicates
Given
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}

ConnectedComponents@list
(* {{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}} *)

ConnectedComponents@list /. Join[AssociationThread[list[[All, 1]] -> list], AssociationThread[list[[All, 2]] -> list]]
(* {{{4, 5}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}}} *)

Notice that {4, 5} is duplicated in the result. It might be that in the OP's data this case never occurs, but if so that wasn't made clear.
Doesn't recover all pairs
Consider this case:
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};

ConnectedComponents@list
(* {{1, 2, 3, 4}} *)

ConnectedComponents@list /. Join[AssociationThread[list[[All, 1]] -> list], AssociationThread[list[[All, 2]] -> list]]
(* {{{1, 4}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}}} *)

Notice we've lost {1, 3}. Since ReplaceAll works on the list of connected vertices, anytime we have more edges than vertices, we'll lose edges.
Improved version
Let's keep the idea of using connected components, but since we're interpreting our original list of pairs as edges of a graph, it would be nice if we could use the built-in EdgeList function for graphs to recover the edges in the connected components. We can do this if we could get the connected components as graphs themselves. Fortunately, that's what ConnectedGraphComponents does.
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}};
ConnectedGraphComponents@list


EdgeList /@ ConnectedGraphComponents@list


We can recover the pairs with
Apply[List, EdgeList /@ ConnectedGraphComponents@list, {2}]
(* {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}, {3, 4}}} *)

or alternatively with
EdgeList /@ ConnectedGraphComponents@list /. UndirectedEdge -> List

Let's apply this to our other test case:
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {10, 11}};
EdgeList /@ ConnectedGraphComponents@list


Okay, we should eliminate the empty lists. I'll do it at the very end of the process:
DeleteCases[Apply[List, EdgeList /@ ConnectedGraphComponents@list, {2}], {}]
(* {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {{10, 11}}} *)

Applying this to the original list:
list = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, 
        {10, 11}, {11, 12}, {12, 13}, {13, 7}, {6, 14}, {14, 4}, 
        {3, 15}, {15, 1}};
DeleteCases[Apply[List, EdgeList /@ ConnectedGraphComponents@list, {2}], {}]
(* {{{7, 8}, {13, 7}, {8, 9}, {12, 13}, {9, 10}, {10, 11}, {11, 12}},
    {{4, 5}, {14, 4}, {5, 6}, {6, 14}}, 
    {{1, 2}, {15, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 15}}} *)

I kept the DeleteCases for generality, it isn't strictly necessary in this case.

thank you! I will update my method soon.

List @@@ # &@*EdgeList /@ ConnectedGraphComponents@list

Or if for some reason not to use ConnectedGraphComponents.
Partition[#, 2] & @@@ 
 FixedPoint[Gather[Flatten /@ #, IntersectingQ] &, list]


nice, 2nd and 3rd in speed test.
